# how to read System's https_proxy variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, proxy, environment-variables

I know how to read environment variable from nodejs `process.env.variable`. I want to read system variable http_proxy which is set from windows environment variable, but `process.env` doesn't show http_proxy variable.

setting that environment from mycomputer->rightClick->properties ->Advensed System Seting -> Environment Variable-> new -> key :https_proxy , value : abc:80

console.log(JSON.stringify(process.env)); dosent shows https_proxy

Comment: How do you set the environment variable? Can you show the code that sets it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get helpful answers, please include the code you have tried so far to solve this problem so we can help you debug or improve it. That's how SO works.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer i have set that environment from mycomputer->rightClick->properties ->Advensed System Seting -> Environment Variable-> new -> key :https_proxy , value : https://abc:80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to consider :

There are system environment variables and user environment variables. What user is the node running as? If you run it in a command window, it is probably running as your user. If you run as a service it will be the Network service user, unless you configured another user.
Is the environment variable visible for the user node is running as?

If you define a new environment variable, it is not automatically accessible everywhere. Node must be restarted to see the new variable. But this may not be sufficient. If you start node from the terminal, consider that in Windows a command window only sees the environment variables that were available when `cmd` was started, and those that were defined inside that terminal. That means, that you need not only to restart node, but also to close and reopen the command window.

Comment: Not restarting webstrom was the issue, Thank you Lorenz Meyer.